# Install .ipa with iTunes 12.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I would like to install an application that I exported as .ipa with Xcode. I exported the file with Xcode 7 Beta and without Apple account developper.
I followed several tutorial to install the application on my iPhone (connecting the device - click on intall - sync)

But it does not. I is not an error message, but the application will not install in full. Loading goes well, and at the time of application installation, everything stopped, and the logo is clouded.

iTunes or the iPhone do not say anything to me about an error eventual.
When I click the application (grayed) iPhone triggers an alert "can not open -titleApplication-" with two options: Cancel or repair.

Answer (score 0):

> I exported the file with Xcode 7 Beta and without Apple account developper

That's a bug in Xcode, then. I'm surprised it allowed you to do that.

You cannot export without a developer account, because you need a distribution profile. For example, you could export as an Ad Hoc Distribution build linked to your device, and you could then install the `.ipa` file through iTunes - but to do that, you would need an Ad Hoc Distribution profile, and you can't obtain one without an Ad Hoc certificate and identity, which required a developer membership.

You can, without a membership, hook your device to your computer and run your app on that device - that's a new feature in Xcode 7. But you cannot usefully export anything without a membership.